# Should we replace the "tpm" tag with "trusted-computing" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Seems like the [tpm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpm) tag isn't used a lot and is mostly always use along with [trusted-computing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trusted-computing) tag.

If someone use the [tpm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpm) tag, implicitly, he's asking a question about trusted computing.

- Should we add the [tpm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpm) tag to all question about [trusted-computing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trusted-computing)?
- Should we add the "tusted computing" tag to question about [tpm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpm)?
- Should we remove the [tpm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpm) tag?
- Should we make them synonyms?

Answer (score 3):

If one using [tpm](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tpm) obviously asks for about [trusted-computing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trusted-computing), the other is not true. You can ask about [trusted-computing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trusted-computing) without talking about TPM at all.

For this reason, I disagree on merging these two.